# Defining a structure with an array

Tags: python, numpy, struct, ctypes

I usually use numpy array, so I have the following `ctypes` type defined in Python

```
arr_double = numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.double, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')
```

I then have the following structure in C

```
struct mystruct {
    double *array;
    size_t size;
};
```

I tried defining this structure in Python using ctypes as follows

```
class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("array", arr_double), ("size", ctypes.c_size_t)]
```

However, this gives me the error

```
second item in _fields_ tuple (index 2) must be a C type
```

What is the correct way to define this structure in ctypes? Is there a way to use numpy's ctypes types? if not, how would I covert a numpy array to a "C type"?

Answer (score 0):

The elements of `ctypes.Structure` must be `ctypes` types, but you can use `numpy.ctypes.data_as` to convert a numpy array to a C type:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

PDOUBLE = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)  # equivalent to C double*

class MyStruct(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('array', PDOUBLE),
                ('size', ct.c_size_t))

    def __init__(self, arr):
        if not isinstance(arr, np.ndarray) or arr.dtype != 'float64' or arr.ndim != 1:
            raise TypeError('parameter 1 must be 1D numpy array of float64')
        self.array = arr.ctypes.data_as(PDOUBLE)
        self.size = len(arr)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'MyStruct({self.array[:self.size]})'

arr = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
s = MyStruct(arr)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
MyStruct([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```